# How to retry an expect statement if it fails in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am using jest to do unit testing in my react application.

I have a material ui date picker in my application with next and previous buttons and I have the current selected date in the browser url. Whenever user clicks next or previous button, the url gets updated.
I used `history.push` to do that and I checked that it's working properly in the ui. But the test case I have to verify this is failing at the following expect statement `expect(history.push).toBeCalledWith('/path/to/url?date=${date}');` saying 0 calls are made to this function. I want to retry only this particular expect statement a couple more times if it fails to make sure that it's not failing due to some delay. How can I do that?

`retry(expect(history.push).toBeCalledWith('/path/to/url?date=${date}'), numTimes);`

Comment: Could be related/unrelated, but how are you using a `history` object in your tests? A mock object? There are other possible ways to test this in a more determinant manner. Mind sharing more of your test code? i.e. the setup and test, maybe also include the component code under test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just use a `setTimeout` with a callback of your `expect` statements and a jest `done()` after. Set the delay to your liking and just be sure you've mocked the `history` object properly.